# Add Hours in String which is coming from database

Tags: android

I have a string format = "2019-07-19 12:10:56"
Which is coming from JSON object.
I want to add 5 hours in it. I am doing this because the time I am getting is 5 hours back.

I have tried this code and this is not successful for me.

```
String time = message_object.get("date").toString();  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(time);
                    formatter.getCalendar().add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
                    //Log.i("1Time",date1.toString());
```

I want to get 5 hours plus time.

Comment: I know that I should some times be careful when it's android. However, if it's like Java you should not use the raw Date class unless absolutely necessary. Much better is to use the LocalDateTime and similar. They also have the utility methods you need :) Be aware they usually return a new object :)

Comment: `this is not successful for me.` what is the problem you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date string should be,

```
String time = "2019-07-19 12:10:56";
```

Now convert it to date and add 5 hours.

```
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time); 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
    time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(calender.getTime()); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
     // Handle your other case here,
     // else display original date.
}

editText.setText(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String time = "2019-07-19 12:10:56";  
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time); 
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
                System.out.println("Date : "+calendar.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```